# an exercise of shafarevich (I.1.8)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have a question related to the following exercise of Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry:

**(I.1.8)** Prove that for any nonsingular points $P_1,\ldots,P_r$ of an irreducible curve and numbers $m_1,\ldots,m_r\geq 0$ there exists a rational function that is regular at all these points, and has a zero of multiplicity $m_i$ at $P_1$.

In his setting we work over an algebraically closed field $k$, and a (plane) curve is defined as the zero-locus of a polynomial $f\in k[x,y]$ in $\mathbb A^2$.

Can I solve the exercise in the following way: let $l_i\in k[x,y]$ be a linear form that is the equation of a line through $P_i$ unequal to the tangent line at $P_i$ and not passing through any of the other points $P_j\ (j\neq i)$. Then take the image of $l_1^{m_1}\cdots l_r^{m_r}$ in the coordinate ring corresponding to the curve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you still need to prove why it is correct.